# Can I host custom forms using Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script

Is it possible to have custom forms created using Google Apps Script to have their own URL just like Google Forms do and be publicly available?

Can I host these custom forms somewhere without using Google Sites? For example, Google Drive?

Please can you point me in right direction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can, by creating a Google Apps Scripts *webapp*.

It is basically a Google Apps Script which has a `doGet()` and/or `doPost()` function.

Your webapp will have a URL similar to that of a Google Form.

See the documentation for [Google Apps Scripts Webapps](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web).

Comment: Thanks for your reply but how can I make the forms viewable to everyone but only editable by a certain number of people like google forms are? Right now, it seems like I have to specifically give permissions to everyone to add them.

Comment: A Google Apps Script Webapp is by default viewable to everyone (they just need to know the public URL). You can give edit permissions to your script from the Script Editor.

Comment: I'm asking for more information here: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/146074/how-do-i-pass-hidden-metadata-into-a-google-apps-scripts-html-service